# UNC path construction on Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, unc

I've got a function that uses `path.join` to construct a UNC path for use by another (Windows) system (the Node.js application does not need access to it, it just needs to construct the path correctly):

```
function constructUncPath (fileName, userLastName) {
  var storageLocation = getStorageLocation(); // Returns a UNC base path
  var todayDateFormatted = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
  return path.join(storageLocation, userLastName + '_' + todayDateFormatted + '_' + fileName);
}
```

On Windows it creates the path correctly, but on Linux it fails because it inserts forward slashes instead of backslashes:

```
 + expected - actual

      -\\path\to/user_20150101_file.txt
      +\\path\to\user_20150101_file.txt
```

Is there a way to force `path.join` to use backslashes instead of forward slashes?

Or should I just explicitly replace them after the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path.join() won't do it as it is picking up the forward slash character from the machine it is running on. There's lots of ways to write a path.join() replacement, but using .Replace("/", "\") is easiest.

Incidentally, if you don't have to support Windows 9x, don't even bother. Windows will take a forward slash there just fine.

Comment: Yep .replace('/'. '\\') seems to do the trick. Although as you say it's not really needed, probably better to just change the test to be slash-agnostic :)